# How to manipulate spoken text with Speak?

Tags: sound

I need to vary the speed, pause, reverse and in general control aspects of the playback of `Speak[]` is this possible?

Comment: You could build up a front end based on `SpokenString[Range[15], Options[Speak], "PostProcess" -> False]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"<volume level=\"100\">  <emph> Update 2 ! </emph> 
 <volume level=\"50\">
 Some examples of text-to-speech <spell> xml </spell> 
 tags that you can inject into the string input for Speak 
 from <spell> XML TTS </spell> Tutorial. 
For example the following <spell> url </spell> is spelled out 
     <spell> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717077(v=vs \
.85).aspx. 
     </spell> 
 and the following text is read backwards at 
 <rate absspeed=\"-5\"> lower speed 
 <voice required=\"Gender=Female\">
    by a female
      <silence msec=\"500\"/> 
        esrever ni nekops eb dluohs txet sihT
      </rate>
 </voice>
 and  <rate absspeed=\"5\"> higher speed <silence msec=\"500\"/>
        esrever ni nekops eb dluohs txet sihT
      </rate>
   </rate>
   </volume> " // Speak
```

See: [XML TTS Tutorial (SAPI 5.3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717077(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
"<rate absspeed=\"5\">
    This text should be spoken at rate five.
    <rate absspeed=\"-5\">
       This text should be spoken at rate negative five.
    </rate>
 </rate>
 <rate absspeed=\"10\"/>" // Speak

"<volume level=\"50\">
 This text should be spoken at volume level fifty.
    <volume level=\"100\">
     This text should be spoken at volume level one hundred.
    </volume>
 </volume>" // Speak

"<rate absspeed=\"5\">
     Next text should be spoken in reverse.
     <rate absspeed=\"-5\">
        esrever ni nekops eb dluohs txet sihT
     </rate>
  </rate>
  <rate absspeed=\"10\"/>" // Speak
```

**Update:** You can insert XML tags into to string input to `Speak` to control voice gender, speed, volume, pitch etc.

Using few examples from [sapisynth](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/voicebox/doc/voicebox/sapisynth.html)

```
"<voice required=\"Gender=Male\"/> <rate absspeed=\"-10\"/> the list  \
<silence msec=\"100\"/> 1 <volume level=\"200\"/> comma  <silence \
msec=\"100\"/> 2 <pitch middle=\"15\"/>  <silence msec=\"100\"/> 3 \
comma  <silence msec=\"100\"/> <volume level=\"20\"/> 4  <rate speed=\
\"10\"/> <voice required=\"Gender=Female\"/> 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12  " //Speak
```

---

Original post:

To play with the speed, you can process the string expression output of `SpokenString` to change the length of `silence` elements.

```
SpokenString[Range[10], Options[Speak], "PostProcess" -> False]
```

> [image]

For example:

```
StringReplace[SpokenString[Range[10], Options[Speak], "PostProcess" -> False], 
   {"100" -> "0", "comma" -> ""}] // Speak
```

Comment: The commands are not the same for OSX as Mathematica sends the text to the system specific speech engine. Here is the corresponding [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SpeechSynthesisProgrammingGuide/FineTuning/FineTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004365-CH5-SW3) for OSX. For example try :`Speak["[[volm 0.3]] You can do [[rate 400]] [[volm 1.5]] many many many many [[rate 50]] things.[[rset 0.]] And [[slnc 1000]] others."]`

Comment: @SquareOne, interesting. I am looking forward to seeing your post.

Comment: I am afraid I don't have anything more interesting to say. I just found these informations concerning OS X and Windows (and [SAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717077%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that you already gave) for this post. Actually I was exactly looking for the same info yesterday for this [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76841/19960) of mine. I missed then the `PostProcess` option revealing that control command can be inserted in the text to fine tune the speech. However I noticed that the speech was sent to a local speech engine.