# How to Speak in a foreign language?

Tags: mac-os-x, sound

A [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20513/how-do-i-change-the-way-mathematica-pronounces-english-words-e-g-futile-is-n) changed the pronunciation by changing the spelling of words or by externally changing the default system voice. This is useful for speaking in foreign languages too, but I don't want to do either of these things because sound correspondences might not exist (what is the English equivalent of the Spanish rolled R?) and toggling the default system voice manually is a pain.

Another [related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76942/how-to-manipulate-spoken-text-with-speak) changed the speed and pauses by inserting operating system specific markup into the spoken string for Windows systems, and a comment pointed to the documentation for OSX. From the accepted answer, it seems changing the voice is easy enough on Windows (I haven't tried it), but how do we do it on OSX? The documentation was not clear enough for me.

**TL;DR**

How can we get `Speak` to use a different voice?

Comment: On a related note, I asked a [similar question](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/572030) about `Speak` on the Raspberry Pi.  Turns out that the RPi version comes packaged with espeak and the configuration files can be tweaked as desired.  I believe this solution is RPi specific, however.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I let *Mathematica* parse the input into a speakable string, but then I send it to the operating system as if going through the command terminal. This allows me to set the voice flag for my installed voices.

```
mySpeak[input_, voice_String:"Allison", options:OptionsPattern[Speak]]:=
  CompoundExpression[
    Run["say -v " <> voice<>" " <> SpokenString[input, options]],
    Null
  ]

mySpeak["Hello, my name is Allison."]
mySpeak["Hola, me llamo Angelica.", "Angelica"]
```

The `say` command is available on OS X.

Comment: In another [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76841/19960) related to the "related question" you cited above, I gave also an example with the `say` OS X specific speech engine ;)

Comment: On my system these voices are not installed by default, the voices `Allison` and `Angelica` have to be downloaded by selecting them under `System Prefereces...` | `Dictation & Speech` | `System Voice` | `Customize...`

Comment: I would write this function as: `mySpeak[input_, voice_String: "Alex",  options : OptionsPattern[SpokenString]] := (Run["say -v " <> voice <> " " <> SpokenString[input, options]];)`. I would use "Alex" as the default voice because I am sure it is installed on all OS X systems. I would use the option pattern for `SpokenString` because that is function called, not `Speak`.

Comment: @m_goldberg, `mySpeak` is supposed to replace `Speak`, so I think the options pattern should be that for `Speak`, but your point is taken. Perhaps the options should be `Filter`ed for those that are compatible with `SpokenString`.

Comment: If `mySpeak` is a replacement for `Speak` why doesn't it call `Speak`?

Comment: @m_goldberg Why should it? It takes the same inputs, serves the same purpose, and (supposedly) returns the same output as `Speak`. It doesn't have to call `Speak` to be a substitute for it.