# How do I keep Speak[] from spelling out words?

Tags: sound

When I input

*Speak["aeiou"]*

it spells out a-e-i-o-u, but I want it to be pronounced as one word.

How do I do this?

Is it even possible?

Comment: I am sure you can increase its speed.

Comment: @thedude I want it pronounced, not spelled, even if it is spelled very fast.

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to do it. I offered a workaround if it turns out to be impossible.

Comment: @thedude thanks for the suggestion though, I will use it if nothing works.

Comment: I don't think it is possible.  After all, how do you know your example shouldn't be pronounced "ah-eh-ih-oh-you"?  If your example isn't a word, *Mathematica* will not have proper guidance on how to pronounce it.

Comment: I think it will involve the same tricks as in [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20513/245](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20513/245)

Comment: @Jens sadly, I have windows and not mac, but I will still look for system preferences! :)

Edit: I can change speed, but that's it!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I don't think it is, as Speak["ae"] makes an "ay" sound, as in "day", but when Speak["aeiou"] is entered, it spells it out, including the "e".

Comment: @Benji b-k.  In v. 10.3, `Speak["ae"]` yields "eee" (not "ay" as in "day").

Comment: @DavidG.Stork wait, what OS are you using? Maybe it differs from OS to OS?

Comment: Mac OS X Yosemite v. 10.10.3.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork That probably is why it is pronounced different, as I am using windows 7.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Speak` uses the native OS text-to-speech engine. So whatever that happens to do with the parsed `SpokenString` is what you are going to get. Not sure how to verify that this is the case but if so, perhaps there is some system-level setting that would fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have figured out:

Speak[] is buggy. Here is proof:

Speak["aeueaaeueauaeaeueaaeuaeaeeaueaaeuae"] can be pronounced, but Speak["aeiou"] is spelled out.

Speak["ae ae ae ae"] pronounces the first three, and spells out the fourth.

Speak[] changes from system to system. On my raspberry pi, the first word of any Speak[] command is left out, but it is not left out on my PC.

So to answer my own question, no, it doesn't appear to be possible. Instead, I should try to use actual words.